# tokenizing on a pdf for quantitative analysis

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, quanteda

I ran into an issue using the unnest_tokens function on a data_frame. I am working with pdf files I want to compare.

```
text_path <- "c:/.../text1.pdf"
text_raw <- pdf_text("c:/.../text1.pdf")
text1df<- data_frame(Zeile = 1:25, 
                      text_raw)
```

So far so good. But here comes my problemo:

```
  unnest_tokens(output = token, input = content) -> text1_long
```

Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `var` has the wrong type `function`.
i It must be numeric or character.

I want to tokenize my pdf files so I can analyse the word frequencies and maybe compare multiple pdf files on wordclouds.

Comment: first, you do not supply text1df to `unnest_tokens`, secondly input should not be content but text_raw.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you mean like this?:

text1df <- unnest_tokens(text1df , output = wort, input = text1df ) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(str_detect(token, "[a-z]")) -> text1df_long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a piece of simple code. I kept your German words so you can copy paste everything.

```
library(pdftools)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidytext)

file_location <- "d:/.../my_doc.pdf"
text_raw <- pdf_text(file_location)
# Zeile 12 because I only have 12 pages
text1df <- data_frame(Zeile = 1:12, 
                     text_raw) 

text1df_long <- unnest_tokens(text1df , output = wort, input = text_raw ) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(wort, "[a-z]"))

text1df_long
# A tibble: 4,134 x 2
   Zeile wort       
   <int> <chr>      
 1     1 training   
 2     1 and        
 3     1 development
 4     1 policy     
 5     1 contents   
 6     1 policy     
 7     1 statement  
 8     1 scope      
 9     1 induction  
10     1 training   
# ... with 4,124 more rows
```